# Graded prime ideals of infinite poylnomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, projective-space, projective-schemes

Consider the infinite polynomial ring, $A$ unital commutative,
$$S= A[x_1,x_2,\ldots ].$$
We give the rings the grading with $\deg x_i=1$. $\operatorname{Proj}S$ denotes the homogeneous prime ideals of $S$ not containing $S_+$, the elements of degree $\ge 1$.

We consider the basic open sets
$$D_+(x_i):= \{ p \in \operatorname{Proj} S \, : \, x_i \notin p \}$$
of homogeneous prime ideals not containing $x_i$.

> Then is it true that $\operatorname{Proj} S = \bigcup_i D_+(x_i)$ and it has no finite subcover?

Comment: What does "infinite / finite polynomial ring" mean?  Is $S_+$ the set of polynomials with $0$ constant term?  (Also, other typos have been fixed, but there's still 'poylnomial' in the title.)

Comment: Sorry, no finite polynomial. And $S_+$ are the positive degree terms. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 2):

(i) It covers. If $\mathfrak{p} \in\operatorname{Proj}S$ lies in complement of $\bigcup_{i} D_+(x_i)$, it contains all $x_i$, which generates $S_+:= \bigoplus _{d \ge 1} S_d$ as an ideal. This contradicts definition of $\operatorname{Proj}S$.

(ii) Suppose there is a finite subcover $\operatorname{Proj}S= \bigcup_1^k D_+(x_i)$. Let $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ be a prime ideal. Then 
$$ \mathfrak{p}_k = (\mathfrak{p}, x_1,\ldots, x_k) $$
is a prime ideal  ($S/\mathfrak{p}_k \simeq (A/\mathfrak{p}) [x_{k+1},\ldots]$ is integral) not contained in the cover.